# Angular 2 ngModelChange Extract targent from callback

Tags: angular

I need to know target of ngModelChange inside its callback.
I tried:

```
...<select id="objet" [(ngModel)]="myVar" (ngModelChange)="myCallback($event,myTarget)" name="objet">...
```

And for myCallback:

```
myCallback($event,myTarget){...}
```

This don't work!

Comment: (change)="myCallback($event,myTarget)"

Comment: `myCallback($event) { console.log($event.target); }` ?

Comment: show the `options` list